# Newbie Flutter Development

Tags: android, flutter

I am new in android app development. I;ve been working on a flutter source code I was able to setup and run the apps on my Huawei Y9 2019, however installing the same apps on Samsung A03 (for testing purposes) installation fails, throws an error

> App not installed as app isn't compatible with your phone

Tried building an APK and ran it directly from the device, same error.
I have installed the app from the official developer using the same device it installed without issues.

Comment: If it says `app isn't compatible with your phone` that usually means your `minSdkVersion` is too high for your device. In other words its not compatible with your device. You need to lower it so it can be compatible. Even if you managed to install the app somehow, some functions and features will not work properly because they use features that are present in newer devices only. You may need to downgrade some libraries/packages to be able to keep your `minSdkVersion` lower